# Refresh Control with Search Display Controller appears overtop the Search Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I have implemented a simple Table View Controller with a Search Display Controller dragged out via Interface Builder. I then enabled refreshing so that a Refresh Control is visible when the user pulls down to refresh.

*The problem is, the spinner is visible on top of the search bar when it should lie underneath it.*

I know the cause is the Minimal Search Style. If you use the default Prominent style, the issue doesn't exist.

When you slowly pull down you'll see the first line appear overtop the search bar like so: 
[image]

If you keep pulling it does show up in the location you expect, but if you push the view back up while it's still refreshing you'll see the spinner on top of the search bar like so:
[image]

As soon as you push it up so that the spinner touches the first section header, the spinner immediately disappears.

This is how it is supposed to look, like it does in Mail - underneath the search bar:
[image]

I tried to fix the problem by simply making the spinner lie underneath the search bar so that it would never appear overtop, but that did not work. Oddly enough, that code caused the spinner to not be visible in the gray area above the table and if you push it up it appears overtop the search bar - exactly opposite of what I would expect. Here is that code:

```
self.refreshControl.layer.zPosition = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.layer.zPosition - 1;
```

**How can I prevent the spinner appearing on top of the search bar when using the Minimal style?**

Comment: I think Andrew's issue here is that you do not show us **how** you are implementing these variations with your code and so it would be very difficult to point to anything that would be a valid solution other than to write a whole tutorial on how views get displayed, stacked and interact. Just vaguely saying that "I make this this way" isn't enough information.

Comment: There is no code required to reproduce the issue. The one line of code is an attempt to fix the issue. I stated everything required to experience the issue: in IB drag out a table view controller, add a search display controller, enable refreshing in the sidebar, run the app. By variations I believe you mean the different screenshots provided? One can see that behavior by dragging their finger on screen. I didn't code that behavior.

Comment: Have you tried setting the z position to a negative number, i.e -1? If those other components are using Z position, then it'd probably be a good idea to test this to see if the layering is messed up between the two

Comment: @theMonster Thanks, but changing it to -1 results in the spinner not appearing at all except when it lies overtop the search bar - the same behavior as the code I previously tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with the Minimal Bar Style. If you set it to Prominent you won't experience the issue. If you use Prominent and try to remove the background, you'll also experience this issue. The only workaround I've found is to try to mimic the Minimal style with the Prominent style applied.

Answer (score 3):

To workaround this bug for `UISearchBarStyleMinimal`, you have to set `backgroundImage` property with any image. Only if background image is set, layout behave correctly.

```
private extension UISearchBar {
    private func setBackgroundColorWithImage(color: UIColor) {
        let rect = self.bounds
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.backgroundImage = image // here!
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you write this code in objective C please ? @Marcin

Answer (score 0):

Move the refresh control behind the search bar when you set it up.

```
refreshControl.layer.zPosition -= 1
```

Answer (score -1):

So if it helps anyone i had the same problem and a fast solution is adding the refreshcontrol as a subview of self.view instead of tableheaderview. This will add the controller above every thing else and at leas you'll be able to see it. On the other hand i believe you could fully corrected y setting it under the correct layer.zPosition. But i haven't had time to fully correct it.

```
[self.view addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```

Comment: Adding that code in `viewDidLoad` didn't work for me, even if I first remove it from its `superview`. It still appears overtop the search bar. Did you have to do anything else?